# Can I use SkyDrive to host and link to JavaScript and CSS files?

Tags: javascript, css, onedrive

I want to host and directly link to a few JS and CSS files from SkyDrive but I am not sure if this is possible. It absolutely *is* possible to share the files publicly to be downloaded, but I need a way to link to these files directly without having to download separately. I see links for 'embed' and 'share' but none of the generated URLs allow me to host the files directly without having to download.

Is it possible to host and allow linking for direct use (similar to Google code) of JS and CSS files on SkyDrive?

Thanks!

Comment: The MS site says you can share with a link so I would think once you got that link you could use that link. "If you’re on a computer, choose Share and then decide how you want to share:

By email.

With a link (handy if you want to copy and paste into an instant message or webpage).

On Facebook, Gmail, Twitter, LinkedIn, and more—you can share SkyDrive files with any contact or network you’ve connected to your SkyDrive account.

Comment: Yep this is easy to do and I have done that. However when trying any of those links, it takes you to the Skydrive site to then download the file. I need it where when the link is used it is actually accessing the CSS or JS file and not having to go to MSFT site to download.

Comment: @atconway can you give us an example file on SkyDrive for which you can't find out the direct link?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for something like http://www.site44.com/ but that only works with DropBox.

Answer (score 3):

The only way I see this work would be if you use the Live Connect API.
You would be required to get an Access Token. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff750952.aspx

And then you can call the files using The Live Connect REST API.
like this:

```
https://apis.live.net/v5.0/file.F147027E527AFCA7.F147027E527AFCA7!118?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN
```

This would return a JSON File with lot of useful information about your Skydrive file.
(Including the actual source path to your .css or .docx or whatever file can be found in the source attribute of the JSON Response)

[image: JSON Responnse to File Object]

In above URL, file. -> indicates you are requesting a file object.
F147027E527AFCA7 is the folder.
F147027E527AFCA7!118 refers to the exact file ID.

You can check out these in your url when you access the files in your Skydrive via browser (or in the share url).

In fact, there's a lot more of use with this API - you can actually do a LOT of things.
msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243648.aspx

Hope it helps! :)